# Test if point is within line range on 2D space

Tags: java, algorithm, math, geometry

This question is a bit hard to formulate so I'll start by showing this image:

[image]

I want to test if points (such as p1 and p2 on the image) are within the dotted lines that are perpendicular to the line at its limits. I know the coordinates of the points to test and the line's limits.

So for p1 it would be false, and for p2 it would be true.

What would be the most computationaly efficient way to calculate this?

I'm working with floats in Java.

Comment: What did you try so far ? What did or did not work ? Post your code please

Comment: I haven't coded anything for that yet as I have no idea how to apprach it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be very efficiently done with the *dot product*:

[image]

This is **positive** if `A` has a component *parallel* to `B`, and **negative** if anti-parallel.

Therefore if you have a line segment defined by points `A` and `B`, and a test point `P`, you only need two dot product operations to test:

`dot(A - B, P - B) >= 0 && dot(B - A, P - A) >= 0`

---

EDIT: a graphical explanation:

[image]

The dot product can be shown to be:

[image]

Thus if `θ > 90` then `dot(A, B) < 0`, and vice versa. Now for your problem:

[image]

In case 1, when `dot(A - B, P - B) > 0` we say that `P` is on the correct side of the dotted line at `B`, and vice versa in case 2. By symmetry we can then do the same operation at `A`, by swapping `A` and `B`.

Comment: Perfect, this is the kind of answer I was hoping for! One line of code and all tests green. :)

Comment: @P.Oring good to hear. The dot product is a *very* useful operation in vector geometry computations - I strongly suggest you read up on it if you are not familiar.

Answer (score 0):

If the point to test (tp), together with start point (sp) and end point (ep) of the range, form an obtuse triangle and you can conclude that it is out of range.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_and_obtuse_triangles

A special case would be tp is same slope as sp and ep, then you calculate the 2 distances:

- distSpAndTp - distance between sp and tp
- distEpAndTp - distance between ep and tp

If the sum of these 2 distances = distance between sp and ep, then tp is in range, otherwise it is out of range.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This approach would involve trigonometry though, right? I was hoping to avoid this for performance reasons. (Or am i worng to worry about that?)

Comment: Hi Oring, don't worry about it, computers are good at maths and are very efficient at doing that :)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to first create a rectangle **Rect** (of *android.graphics* package), with x and width being the beginning and end of line, and y and height being the beginning and end of screen height.
Then use the **Rect** *method* ***Rect.contains(int x, int y)*** to check if the point coordinates lie within.

For floats, use ***RectF*** class instead.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not in an Android environment.

Comment: Rectangular is also available in java. I don't understand what are the bounds of the proposed rectangle.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned it but I'm interrested in an algorithm, I don't want to use a library.
I'm not proposing a rectangle. If you're reffering to the dotted lines, they are just a visual illustration of what I mean by "within line range".

Answer (score 0):

This approach involves using 2D vectors (which you should have been using anyway, makes working in any coordinate system a lot easier) and the dot (scalar) product. It does not require any relatively expensive operations like the square root or trignometic functions, and therefore is very performant.

Let `A` and `B` be the start and end points (by point I mean a vector representing a position in 2D space) of the line segment, in any order. If `P` is the point to test, then:

- If `dot(PA, AB)` and `dot(PB, AB)` have the same sign, the point lies *outside* the region (like `p1` in your example).
- If the dot products above have opposite signs, the point lies *inside* the region (like `p2`).

Where `PA = A - P`, `PB = B - P` and `AB = B - A`.

This condition can be surmised as follows:

```
if dot(PA, AB) * dot(PB, AB) <= 0 {
   // Opposite signs, inside region
   // If the product is equal to zero, the point is on one of the dotted lines
}
else {
   // Same signs, outside region
}
```

Comment: Not sure if the cost of the extra multiplication is out-weighed by the saving of one comparison operation

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, **x1** is the beginning of the line and **x2** is the end. Then **ax** is the dot in an horizontal plan and; **y1**, **y2** and **ay** in vertical plan.

> if((ax >= x1 && ax <= x2) && (ay >= y1 && ay <= y2)){ // do your work
>   }

Answer (score 0):

There are a few answers already but there is another solution that will give you the unit distance on the line segment that the points is perpendicular to.

Where then line is `x1`,`y1` to `x2`,`y2` and the point is `px`,`py`

Find the vector from line start to end

```
vx = x2 - x1;
vy = y2 - y1;
```

And the vector from the line start (or end) to the point

```
vpx = px - x1;
vpy = py - y1;
```

And then divide the dot product of the two vectors by the length squared of the line.

```
unitDist = (vx * vpx + vy * vpy) / (vx * vx + vy * vy);
```

If the perpendicular intercept is on the line segment then `unitDist` will be  `0 <= unitDist <= 1`

In shortened form

```
x2 -= x1;
y2 -= y1;
unitDist = (x2 * (px - x1) + y2 * (py - y1)) / (x2^2 + y2^2);
if (unitDist >= 0 && unitDist <= 1) {
    // point px,py perpendicular to line segment x1,y1,x2,y2
}
```

You also get the benefit of being able to get the point on the line where the intercept is.

```
p2x = vx * unitDist + x1;
p2y = vy * unitDist + y1;
```

And thus the distance that the point is from the line (note not line segment but line)

```
dist = hypot(p2x - px, p2y - py);
```

Which is handy if you are using a point to select from many lines by using the minimum distance to determine the selected line.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved nicely using complex numbers.

Let `a` and `b` the endpoints of the segment. We use the transformation that maps the origin `0` to `a` and the point `1` to `b`. This transformation is a similarity and its expresion is simply

```
p = (b - a) q + a
```

as you can verify by substituting `q=0` or `q=1`. It maps the whole stripe perpendicular to the given segment to the stripe perpendicular to the segment `0-1`.

Now the inverse transform is obviously

```
q = (p - a) / (b - a),
```

and the desired condition is

```
0 <= Re((p - a) / (b - a)) <= 1.
```

To avoid the division, you can rewrite

```
0 <= Re((p - a) (b - a)*) <= |b-a|²
```

or

```
0 <= (px - ax)(bx - ax) + (py - ay)(by - ay) <= (bx - ax)² + (by - ay)².
```